# Cisco C3560CX Interface number/name question

Tags: cisco, interface, sfp

The Cisco C3560CX's come in flavors that include 10gbs SFP+ ports (e.g. WS-C3560CX-12PD-S), and also less expensive ones that only do 1gbs SFP (e.g. WS-C3560CX-12TC-S). Documentation shows you can put in a 1gbs SFP as well as 10gbs SFP+ in the same port. We are considering buying a bunch as well as spares.

Can someone clarify how the interface names will look in each? The client is considering whether they can just spare the lower models with the higher models, or need both, as relates to ...

Specifically, will the 1gbs only interface names of the C3560CX-12TC-S be identical to the interface names on the C3560CX-12PD-S when the latter has 1gbs SFP's?  I.e. does both the name, segment and port all match?

This relates to whether I can take a config from the former (WS-3560CX-12TC-S), swap PIM's in the higher end (WS-3560CX-12PD-S) to SFP (non-plus), and load it into the later for a quick replacement, or will someone have to edit the configs?

Comment: The tengigabit interface will change name to gigabit interface, when you insert a 1 Gbit SFP module.

Comment: I presumed the name portion would change, but does it change into the same segment and port number.  For example, the lower end switch MIGHT be GigabitEthernet0-13 and on the other GigabitEthernet0/0-12 and GigabitEthernet1/0-1.  Does the 1gbs only and 10gbs only (with 1gbs SFP) match?

Comment: Port range is Gi0/1-14 and Ten0/1-2 - if you add a normal SFPs to the SFP+ ports, then Ten0/1 becomes Gi0/15 and Ten0/2 becomes Gi0/16.

Comment: @Cown, thanks, I presume the version which has no 10gbs it follows the same.  That's what I needed to know, if you want to put it in as an answer, and thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had forgotten I posted this question, and now have similar hardware in hand and the answers above may not be correct. I wanted to post what I know in case anyone else is anticipating this issue.

We purchased the WS-C3560CX-12TC-S, which is only gigabit, and those appear as gigabit 0/15 and 0/16, continuing the numbering of the last regular port gi0/14. They are running

**C3560CX Software (C3560CX-UNIVERSALK9-M), Version 15.2(6)E1**

We also have access to one WS-C3560CX-12PD-S, which does tenGig, and it is running

**Cisco IOS Software, C3560CX Software (C3560CX-UNIVERSALK9-M), Version 15.2(4)E4,                                               RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc2)**

On that one the ports are numbered as GigabitEthernet1/0/1 thrugh 16, then TenGigabitEthernet1/0/1 and 1/0/2.  Because that one is not completely under our control I have not had opportunity to plug in a 1g SFP, but I find it interesting the numbers are different entirely with three segments not two, perhaps because of the separate ten gig section (though read on).

Finally we have 3650's (WS-C3650-24TD) running

**Cisco IOS Software [Denali], Catalyst L3 Switch Software (CAT3K_CAA-UNIVERSALK9-M), Version 16.3.6, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc3)**

These I have experimented with, and their ports are numbered:

```
GigabitEthernet 1/0/1 thru 24
GigabitEthernet1/1/1 thru 1/1/2
TenGigabitEthernet1/1/3 thru 1/1/4
```

This one also restarts the numbering in the SFP section but numbers the gig and tengig section sequentially.  When you plug in a 1G SFP into the latter ports, they remain TenGigabitEthernet1/1/3 or 1/1/4 and do not change names (nor numbers).

```
#show int te1/1/4 cap
TenGigabitEthernet1/1/4
  Model:                 WS-C3650-24TD
  Type:                  1000BaseSX SFP
```

So while I cannot confirm the behavior with a 3560 (since I have not had opportunity to plug a 1g pim into a 10g capable slot), the 3650 definitely does not change names when that is done, and these are all running pretty similar IOS-XE versions.

So my GUESS is that the answer to the original question is that they do not change names or numbers.  If I have opportunity to try that other 3560 I will update this.

Answer (score 3):

Port range is Gi0/1-14 and Ten0/1-2 - if you add a normal SFP to the SFP+ ports, then Ten0/1 becomes Gi0/15 and Ten0/2 becomes Gi0/16.

Example:

```
Gi0/15  Uplink             connected    trunk      a-full a-1000 1000BaseSX SFP
Te0/2   Uplink             connected    trunk        full    10G SFP-10GBase-LR
```

Comment: Actually on a 3650 the port remains TenGigabitEthernet even if a 1gb SFP is inserted.  The 3560's only support 1gb SFP's, and they came out of the box as GigabitEthernet and do not change whether the SFP is inserted or not.  The 3650 was a surprise given the answer above, in that they do not change names.  I do not know what a WS-C3560CX-12PD-S (with 2x10G) would be named.

Answer (score 3):

- WS-C3560CX-12TC-S has 12 Gigabit copper ports and 4 uplinks: (2x1G copper and 2x1G SFP), and it does NOT support PoE:

  - Its port format/naming is Gi0/1, Gi0/2, ..., Gi0/16;
- WS-C3560CX-12PD-S has 12 Gigabit copper ports and 4 uplinks: (2x1G copper and 2x10G SFP+), and it supports PoE:

  - As Cown mentioned, its port format/naming is Gi0/1, Gi0/2, ..., Gi0/14, Te0/1 and Te0/2; and when you insert a SFP module into a Te SFP+ port, it should change to Gi port (otherwise it is due to IOS bug).